# r - strange characters when getting tabledata using xpathSApply

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

I am uisng XML package in R to scrape table. However, I get some strange characters in the results after scraping the table. Here are my scripts to get table:

```
TUrlhtml <- htmlParse(htmlfile)
TUrlTable <- xpathSApply(TUrlhtml, 
                          "//table[@class='results_table']/tr/td",
                          xmlValue)
```

And here is the result I got:

```
[1] ""                                  "\xc2\xa02 HK"                      "Clp Holdings Limited\xc2\xa0"     "\xc2ec-00\xc2\xa0"             "66.60\xc2\xa0"        
[6] "\xc2\xa026-Feb-12\xc2\xa0"      "\xc2\xa0"                          ""                                  "\xc2\xa03 HK"                      "Hong Kong & China Gas Co\xc2\xa0"
[11] "\xc2un-03\xc2\xa0"             "21.40\xc2\xa0"                   "\xc2\xa019-Mar-12\xc2\xa0"      "\xc2\xa0"
```

However, when I use internet explorer or firefox to view the html file, there is absolutely no problem with the html file itself. How should I resolve it? Thanks a lot for your valuable advice!
Here is my html file:

```
<table id="main_table" class="results_table" bgcolor="white" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><thead style="background-color: white;"><tr class="top_row" style="padding-bottom: 3px; color: #0033cc"><th style="vertical-align:bottom">
<!--si--><link rel="stylesheet" href="/classes/user_interface/vertical_menu_panel@12.41.004@.css" type="text/css" >      <div class="yui-skin-sam">
      <div class="vertical_menu_panel" style="display:none">
        <div class="hd" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="bd">
          <ul> <li class="primary_sort_ascending"><img class="primary_sort_ascending" src="/images/primary_sort_ascending.gif"/>&nbsp;Sort Asc<span class="action" style="display:none">primary_sort_ascending</span></li> <li class="primary_sort_descending"><img class="primary_sort_descending" src="/images/primary_sort_descending.gif"/>&nbsp;Sort Desc<span class="action" style="display:none">primary_sort_descending</span></li> <li class="add_column"><img class="add_column" src="/images/add_column_left.gif"/>&nbsp;Add Column Here<span class="action" style="display:none">add_column</span></li> <li class="remove_column"><img class="remove_column" src="/images/subtract_small.gif"/>&nbsp;Remove Column<span class="action" style="display:none">remove_column</span></li>          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="ft" style="display:none"></div>
      </div>
      </div>
<input style="" type="checkbox" id="master_check_box" title="Select All">
</th>      <td width="" valign="middle" align="center" nowrap><img alt="" border=0 src="/images/shim.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
  <td width="75" valign="bottom" nowrap class="txtScreen column_header">&nbsp;<span style="text-decoration: underline;"><br><br><br>Ticker</span><IMG alt="" border="0" height="8" src="/images/b_sort_flat_rv.gif" width="10">&nbsp;  <img class="menu_icon" style="position:absolute; vertical-align:bottom; display:none" border="0" src="/images/arrow_down_button.gif"/>   <span class="attributes" style="display: none"><span class="column_id">0</span><span class="display_name">Ticker</span></span></td>
                          <td valign="bottom" align="left" nowrap class="txtScreen column_header  "><span href="#" onclick="return false"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Company Name</span>                           <img class="menu_icon" style="position:absolute; vertical-align:bottom; display:none" border="0" src="/images/arrow_down_button.gif"/> <span class="attributes" style="display: none"><span class="column_id">2886069004</span><span class="display_name">Company Name</span></span></td>
                          <td valign="bottom" align="center" nowrap class="txtScreen column_header  "><span href="#" onclick="return false"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Last<br>Quarter<br>Date</span>                           <img class="menu_icon" style="position:absolute; vertical-align:bottom; display:none" border="0" src="/images/arrow_down_button.gif"/> <span class="attributes" style="display: none"><span class="column_id">2886070004</span><span class="display_name">Last Quarter Date</span></span></td>
                          <td valign="bottom" align="center" nowrap class="txtScreen column_header  "><span href="#" onclick="return false"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Price</span>                           <img class="menu_icon" style="position:absolute; vertical-align:bottom; display:none" border="0" src="/images/arrow_down_button.gif"/> <span class="attributes" style="display: none"><span class="column_id">2886071004</span><span class="display_name">Price</span></span></td>
                          <td valign="bottom" align="center" nowrap class="txtScreen column_header  "><span href="#" onclick="return false"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Date of<br>Last Report</span>                           <img class="menu_icon" style="position:absolute; vertical-align:bottom; display:none" border="0" src="/images/arrow_down_button.gif"/> <span class="attributes" style="display: none"><span class="column_id">2886072004</span><span class="display_name">Date of Last Report</span></span></td>
        <td width="100%" class="txtScreen">&nbsp;</td></tr>
      </thead>
        <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">          <th style="height: 15px">
          <input class="select_cb" type="checkbox" style="height: 13px">
          <span class="attributes" style="display: none"><span class="security_id">28411</span></span>
          </th>
                <td valign="middle" align="center"></td>



        <td align="left" nowrap class="txtScreen">&nbsp;<a href="/stocks/stocks.phtml?security_id=28411&ticker=2+HK" target="_parent" >2 HK</a></td>
        <td align="left" nowrap class="txtScreen" title="Company Name">Clp Holdings Limited&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" nowrap class="txtScreen" title="Last&#13;Quarter&#13;Date">&nbsp;&nbsp;Dec-00&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" nowrap class="txtScreen" title="Price">66.60&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" nowrap class="txtScreen" title="Date of&#13;Last Report">&nbsp;&nbsp;26-Feb-12&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">          <th style="height: 15px">
          <input class="select_cb" type="checkbox" style="height: 13px">
          <span class="attributes" style="display: none"><span class="security_id">48569</span></span>
          </th>
                <td valign="middle" align="center"></td>



        <td align="left" nowrap class="txtScreen">&nbsp;<a href="/stocks/stocks.phtml?security_id=48569&ticker=3+HK" target="_parent" >3 HK</a></td>
        <td align="left" nowrap class="txtScreen" title="Company Name">Hong Kong & China Gas Co&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" nowrap class="txtScreen" title="Last&#13;Quarter&#13;Date">&nbsp;&nbsp;Jun-03&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" nowrap class="txtScreen" title="Price">21.40&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" nowrap class="txtScreen" title="Date of&#13;Last Report">&nbsp;&nbsp;19-Mar-12&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: in you xml example..there isn't a table screening_results_table..maybe you meant `[@class=results_table]`?

Comment: @agstudy: yes, you are correct, I meant [@class=results_table], sorry for the typo. Do you have any idea on how to resolve? I am quite fresh to html ;)  I want to get the table values (without any format), including the headers in the table.

Comment: Try this `as.data.frame(readHTMLTable(TurlHtml)`

Comment: @agstudy: thanks, I have tried readHTMLTable(TurlHtml), but still get the strange characters, when I tried as.data.frame, gets error of "Error in make.names(vnames, unique = TRUE): invalid multibyte string 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by the non breaking &nbsp; space.

That is the unicode character 0xA0, which is \xC2\xA0 in UTF-8.

I don't know why it is also inserting EE7B in-between.

Comment: thanks for the note, do you have any solution? Interesting thing is that when I use internet explorer or firefox to open the html, there is no problem at all in viewing the texts in the table, then I guess there should be some tricks to handle that in R?

Comment: You could use a regex to replace all the &amp;nbsp; by an  space  character before  parsing the html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just wonder why internet explorer and firefox can handle that but R cannot?

Comment: The EE7B might just be a bug in the R entity decoder (since it is not consistently, makes no sense, and is sometimes inserted and sometimes not), but the \xC2\xA0 is actually the correct way of the parser to handle it. It should appear as a single space if shown on the screen. It's just tricky to work with. If the parser would replace it by a space, you would not be able to save the file unchanged as html again.